# How do I find common attendees in two Facebook events?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

If given two public Facebook events, is it possible to find common event attendees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to find common attendees.

But you can use some tools and export the guest list of Facebook events. Then compare both list to get common attendees.

There are some tools to export the guest list:

- [evu.li](http://evu.li/) (Exports to CSV)
- [Attendium](https://attendium.com/facebook-event-exporter)

Comment: It seems then an idea for app. Downloading and comparing is a pain but thanks for the answer. I'll accept it. 

Is there any update to this question?

Comment: @DarrynBrisdaz: As of now no update.

Comment: Any updates now?

Comment: Or now? I think this answer is no longer valid with the updates in permission.